# Opening a list of files and executing a script

Tags: python

I wanted to list all the .pdb files and .ent files and execute the script and prints the sequence but it seems the program is not running properly and it does not show me any result.The code is

```
    import os
    path="c:/pdb"
    dirs=os.listdir(path)
    for file in dirs:
        list1=[]
        for lines in file:
            list=lines.split()
            id=list[0]
            if id=='ATOM' or id=='HETATM':
                if list[4]=='A':
                    if list[2]=='C4':
                        list1.append(list[3])
         print("The sequence is:" ,list1)
```

Comment: You can collapse those 3 `if`s into one. Also, consider a different name to `id`, since that'll hide the builtin `id()` function.

Comment: I want to check conditions so i cannot collapse the three if s . I changed id to someother name but didn't work. The code works fine for one file but does not work if i open the directory and automate it for all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.listdir return a list of strings [1] so you can't do "for lines in file" on them (doing that, you just iterates over file name string, not over file contents). You can use os.walk() [2] for this, e.g.:

```
import os
path = 'c:/pdb'
for dirpath, dirnames, fnames in os.walk(path):
    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.endswith('txt'):
            with open(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)) as fp:
                for line in fp:
                    <program logic here>
```

Also remember not to use reserved words like "list" or "id" - check those here docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

[2] https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Thankyou so much!!

Comment: @SushmitaPal Consider accepting this answer. Click the tick on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Working on windows, you can try specifying your path with an escaped backslash.

```
import os
path = "c:\\pdb"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    list1 = []
    for lines in open(file):
        list = lines.split()
        idl = list[0]
        if (idl == 'ATOM' or idl == 'HETATM') and list[4]=='A' and list[2]=='C4':
            list1.append(list[3])

    print("The sequence is:", list1)
```

Also, the `if`s have been collapsed but they do the same thing. Overly deep indentations can hinder readability.

Comment: It didn't worked . The problem is just that is shows me an empty list. The code works fine with one file.